# Maven Assembly - copy just file from sub-folder when extracting from archive

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a very specific requirement of our build infrastructure to copy some contents of another JAR dependency to a specific sub-folder of my web-application. We're using maven-assembly-plugin, and a natural way to do this is to use `<dependencySet>` along with `<unpackOptions>`.

The code sample (in assembly descriptor) I have looks as following:

```
    <dependencySet>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
        <includes>
            <include>my.group:artifact:jar</include>
        </includes>
        <unpackOptions>
            <includes>
                <include>subfolder/config.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </unpackOptions>
        <outputDirectory>WEB-INF/otherfolder</outputDirectory>
    </dependencySet>
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to specify that I only want to copy just a single file `artifact.jar/subfolder/config.xml` to a target `WEB-INF/otherfolder`. The actual result is `WEB-INF/otherfolder/subfolder/config.xml`. As you can see, `/subfolder` gets appended to a final path. Is there any way to change the `<include>` expression so that `/subfolder` doesn't get appended?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to remove the otherfolder from the outputDirectory ?

Comment: @khmarbaise In that case I will get WEB-INF/subfolder/config.xml. But the expected result is WEB-INF/otherfolder/config.xml

Comment: try **/config.xml and see what happens..

Comment: @om39a The full path is appended, just like in the original descriptor...

Comment: @ArtursLicis Buddy.. Check [this link](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#dependencySet) I think this is wat you need.

Comment: @om39a Thanks, it's a good link, but I already investigated this doc number of times.. Unpack options are specifically described [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_unpackOptions), but they say nothing about any additional expression options. I think I'll have to download maven-assembly-plugin sources and find & review the path resolution part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsing through source reveals that this is not possible via maven-assembly plug-in. It gets all includes that are specified in assembly descriptor, and then passes this information to Plexus archiver which is used through multiple stages. Include patterns are passed to Plexus archiver as well, and then it obviously performs 'unpack' conserving directory structure.

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever thought about the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html) which has a good support for unpacking archives.

Comment: I have thought, and I will rethink again as I will clean up the build scripts. But, to be honest, this is not an answer to a question.

Answer (score 1):

As @khmarbaise indicates, the solution lies in combining dependency-plugin with assembly-plugin:

- On package phase start by unpacking the dependencies you need to some target directory
- On package (later in pom) use assembly  to extract specific files from that directory into your artifact

Answer (score 0):

Try this out with the `<file/>` tag and `destName`:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_file